# Run code in Hibernate Filters

Tags: hibernate, grails, filter, shiro, jsecurity

I have a fairly sophisticated security mechanism that I implemented using Apache Shiro (formerly JSecurity).  In order to know the exact visibility rules for an object, I need to run some code (i.e. lookup user's roles, permissions, groups, etc).  I'd like to run queries that tell me objects that the current user is authorized to see.

I found that hibernate filters give you ability to apply a filter to your objects / queries, which seems to be what I could use here.

However, the examples I found seem to be centered on the database (i.e. say I have a field / column isVisible, filter whenever it's set to true).   Is there a way I can run some code as a hibernate filter, or is it just a thin layer that adds a little WHERE clause to all your queries.

I am actually using this inside Grails / GORM infrastructure, so perhaps there are some other solutions that are valid.  A [plugin exists](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) that integrates hibernate filters, but unless I can use it with some code to run as part of hibernate filtering process, it won't really help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Hibernate filters will not solve your problem.  They can be very useful, but it is exactly a thin layer that adds a little WHERE clause to every fetch.

Since you're using Grails, you might find that AOP will give you what you're looking for.  Take a look at this: http://www.infoq.com/articles/aop-with-groovy

Good luck.